# Excel VBA: How to create custom color filter (combo box control with all option) in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a need: create a combo box (or maybe something else) to filter my file by COLOR and INCLUDING ALL OPTION.

sample data listed below. Goal is when color red, orange, or yellow selected at B7 Combo Box, rows under column c will be filtered accordingly with understanding that any uncolored rows will be kepted. Also there will be an option of ALL.

Any of your suggestions will be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Colour is not data. It is metadata at best, but using colour to classify data is the wrong approach. Data is based on value, whereas colour is about cell presentation and formatting.

Use hard and fast data instead like numbers (1, 2, 3) or text (red, orange, yellow) in a separate "category" column of the data source. Then you can easily use conditional formatting based on the category values to assign the desired colours for visual appeal.

With numbers or text as the classification system, you can then quite easily build formulas to analyse and evaluate the data (Sumifs(), Countifs(), etc). Cell fill colours will not play at all with formulas. While Excel can filter by colours in a table, it is not a good idea to use colour as the sole means of data classification, because counting, summing or building pivot tables classifications is not possible with only colours.